# jQuery check for empty variable

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js markup:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.rhpcon', function(e) {  
    var rhp_name = jQuery(this).find('.rhi').data("name");

    var my_html = '<div class="rhfi">'+ rhp_name +'</div>'; 
        my_html += '<div class="something">Show something else</div>';                          
    jQuery('.rh_pop').html(my_html);                        
});
```

As you can see, the `rhp_name` variable is used in the hardcoded html.

However, there are scenarios where `data-name` does not exist (ie, no `rhp_name` variable).

In a scenario where there is no `rhp_name` variable, I don't want the first `my_html` line to be used.

How do I check if the `var` is empty and so on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(typeof rhp_name !== 'undefined' && rhp_name != ''){
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

```
if (rhp_name.length > 0) 
    console.log("rhp_name exists");
```

Comment: if the variable rhp_name is undefined, calling `length` on it will cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation if the attribute is not set .data returns an empty string. So then you could try:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.rhpcon', function(e) {  
    var rhp_name = jQuery(this).find('.rhi').data("name");
    if(rhp_name!=""){
         var my_html = '<div class="rhfi">'+ rhp_name +'</div>';
         my_html += '<div class="something">Show something else</div>'; 
         jQuery('.rh_pop').html(my_html);
    }
});
```